# how to alert if time ends

Tags: javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
        var current_minutes = mins-1
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        if( seconds > 0 ) { 
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);

        } else {

            if(mins > 1){  

               // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithors
               setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);
              alert("time has ended");
              //here i have to auto submit the form when time ends   
            }
        }
    }
    tick();
}

countdown(10);

</script>
```

how to show alert when the time has ended and the timer should stop running i have tried the following code the but timer stops as (00.00) and it does not show any alert messsage  and i want to auto submit a form if ends, can anyone help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You will need another `else` condition.

Try this:

```js
function countdown(minutes) {
  var seconds = 60;
  var mins = minutes

  function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
    var current_minutes = mins - 1
    seconds--;
    counter.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
    if (seconds > 0) {
      setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {
      if (mins > 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          countdown(mins - 1);
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        alert("time has ended");
      }
    }
  }
  tick();
}

countdown(2);;
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: thank you @ rayon. its working may i know how to auto submit a form wen time ends?

Comment: `document.getElementById('YOUR_FORM_ID').submit()`

Comment: How will the OP know why their code didn't work and what this does to fix that?

Comment: may i know how to get the time spent by the user if submits ? Help me